# How do you offer the ability to change the subscription frequency of your app from the Google Play Store?

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing, in-app-subscription

My app offers a monthly subscription right now, and we are in the process of adding annual subscriptions as well. The user should be able to upgrade/downgrade their subscription, and it looks like this is possible to do within the app, using Google's In-App Billing API as explained [here](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions.html#upgrade).

Buried at the bottom of [this page](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/7018481?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en), however (click on "Change the frequency of your subscription"), it seems that we can offer the ability to change subscription frequency from the Play Store, in the "Manage Subscriptions" section. I cannot find anything that explains how this happens, so my question is - how can we take advantage of this? Will this option automatically show up if we programmatically implement upgrading/downgrading within the app? Is there anything else we need to do to allow the user to upgrade/downgrade directly from the Play Store?